# Is it possible to change to the underline height from when the developer uses `text-decoration: underline;` in CSS to create an underline?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change to the underline height from when the developer uses `text-decoration: underline;` in CSS to create an underline?

Using CSS I made the word "about" which has an 'id' of '#title4' have an underline and I was wondering how I can change the distance of the height from the underline to the word so there is a bigger gap between both?

Example of what I'm looking for

[image]

```
#title4 {
font-size: 2.5rem;
font-weight: 700;
margin-top: 5rem;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Site code](https://jsfiddle.net/nab6zLzb/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

unfortunately, you cannot control `text-decoration` height and spacing between text. So I have used `border-bottom`. Hopefully, this will help you.

```css
#title4 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center" id="title4">About</h1>
```

Comment: It is now possible on recents browsers with `text-decoration-thickness` and `text-underline-offset`

Answer (score 16):

The text-decoration-thickness CSS property sets the thickness, or width, of the decoration line that is used on text in an element, such as a line-through, underline, or overline.

(Edge 87, Firefox 70, Safari 12, Chrome 87)

Syntax: auto | from-font |  |

e.g.

```css
 .css_class
{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-thickness: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_class">Test</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `text-underline-offset` to set the separation space between words and underline

Answer (score 10):

I am late, but this could still be useful to someone.
By using `text-underline-offset: ...px` you can change the gap between those.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `background` instead of `border` or `text-decoration` to have full control.

```css
span {
  --color: red;
  --position: center bottom;
  --width: 50px;
  --height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--color), var(--color)) var(--position) / var(--width) var(--height) no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font: bold 2.5rem sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span>ABOUT</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do just that and that's it .**

```css
#explore{
        background-color: #5C6BC0;
        width: 80px;
        height: 8px;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .text{
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="text">Explore<span id="explore"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for. Try using border-bottom as explained here:

https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot do it but there is a work-around as such.

If you go something like: `#tile4 {border-bottom: 2px; solid #CCC; padding-bottom: 4px}`
So basically, your bottom border becomes your 'underline'.

And you can adjust the padding-bottom to whatever you wish, same goes for the colour and the width of the actual underline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element

```
#title4 {
position: relative;
font-size: 2.5rem;
font-weight: 700;
margin-top: 5rem;
padding-bottom: 15px;}

#title4:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 3px;
background: #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

just add the following css code

```css
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #0000ff;
    text-decoration-thickness: 3px; // underline thickness
    -moz-text-decoration-color: #0000ff;
    text-underline-offset: 20px; // height of underline from text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `text-underline-offset`:

```css
#title4 {
    text-underline-offset: 0.15em; /* Add this line */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```